# Grouping pandas columns under new column created from top row of DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I have a dataframe read from an excel file that looks like this:

```
     |Unnamed: 0 |Unnamed: 1 |Unnamed: 3 | Unnamed: 4|
     |-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
row0 |A          |NaN        |B          |NaN        |
row1 |Option 1   |Option 2   |Option 3   |Option 4   |
row2 |data       |data       |data       |data       |
.
.
.
```

And I want to set the non-NaN first row values as the column names for two columns: `A` and `B` and then create subcolumns (like how it works with MultiIndex) so that I have something like this:

```
     |           A           |           B           |
     |-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
     |Option 1   |Option 2   |Option 3   |Option 4   |
     |-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
row0 |data       |data       |data       |data       |
.
.
.
```

I feel like the easiest way would be to do something like `df.transpose().set_index([row0,row1])` but that doesn't get rid of the NaNs in the first row. Does anyone have any ideas for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use forward fill to deal with the `NaN`s and then make it into a multindex from tuples based on the first two rows.

```
tuples = list(zip(df.loc['row0',:].fillna(method='ffill'), df.loc['row1',:]))
df = df.loc['row2',:]
df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples)

#df
      0    1  2    3
row0  A  NaN  B  NaN
row1  a    b  c    d
row2  1    2  3    4

#df with multiIndex
A  a    1
   b    2
B  c    3
   d    4
Name: row2, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks! Super helpful. If anyone looks at this later, in order to get this to work with multiple rows I had to transpose `df = df.loc['row2',:]` like this `df = df.loc['row2':,:].transpose()`